# No Activity found to handle Intent for old deep link in new version

Tags: android

Recently I have updated my app to 1.2.1 to 1.2.2 and I made a change in deep link url that is my old web url changed to new so I removed it from manifest and released new build but in the new build the old deep link works but when I open the app it crashed with

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=//www.oldurl.com (has extras) }
   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1815)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1513)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3933)
```

below is my new manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.domain.ui.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/BaseTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="@string/deep_host_1"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

And I made only change in

```
 <string name="deep_host_1">www.old.com</string>

 to

 <string name="deep_host_1">www.new.com</string>
```

Comment: can you show the manifest file , both old and new..

Comment: and also the old deep link and new deep link.. that will help us to rectify the problem

Comment: www.old.com & www.new.com both have different domain name?

Comment: yes these are different url